# What is the foam stuff that semiconductors come in?

Tags: antistatic

Sometimes when I order semi-conductors, there pins are put in this black foam (im guessing static sensitive stuff). If I put a high voltage through it, it conducts and burns. What is this stuff called and what is it made out of?

Comment: I can't answer your questions, but it's indeed to prevent static stuff. MOSFETs for example are very sensitive for static charges (that's why you have to discharge yourself before soldering them), so they have to be packed in that black foam.

Comment: +1 <sarcasm> for running a high voltage through something you have no idea about!  </sarcasm>

Comment: wait so its bad to remove it from the foam when I store it? I never have had a problem with leaving it in a plastic bag.

Comment: For most semiconductors it doesn't really matter. There are static-sensitive parts, like MOSFETs, that do care. They may explode when you remove them without first discharging yourself.

Comment: irfp250 and irfp450 don't explode :)

Comment: Whether ambient ESD is a problem seems to depend mostly on ambient humidity. I've _rarely_ had a problem with it myself, but that's not to say it's not real.

Comment: is there like a youtube video of a mosfet exploding when you take it out of its package?

Comment: It's probably foam! ;)

Comment: ESD damage while handling the parts is very real and must be taken seriously.  The problem with ESD is that you might not see the damage for months or years later.  Typically, an ESD discharge has to be more than 500+ volts to be felt/heard/seen, but damage can occur at much lower voltages.  If you haven't had issues with ESD then you either haven't been doing EE long enough, or you did have damage but just didn't recognize it as such.  And it is not at all limited to MOSFETs.  Any semiconductor can be damaged, and even some caps and resistors!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The black stuff is a rubber and/or plastic foam that is heavily loaded with elemental carbon (graphite) in order to make it conductive. It keeps the pins effectively "shorted" together (through a resistive path), and if it's sitting on a grounded surface, it also provides a current-limited path for ESD currents, helping to prevent damage to the parts.

It's cheap and effective for short-term storage, but I've found that over long periods of time, it can break down and/or absorb moisture and corrode the leads of parts that are stuck into it.

Comment: how long is the period of time that I can safely leave it?

Comment: Probably up to a year or two; beyond that, it becomes problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, it prevents a difference in electrical potential that could be discharged through the circuit which could damage or destroy the chip.

[THIS](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL68D38506732FA99D) series produced by Apple in the '80s, while it seems to have a hint of propaganda, is very well done, and explains the risk well.